# Codeigniter View returns only last row query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im new to CI/PHP/development. Im stuck on this problem. It seems to be really basic but i just cant get it right!

The problem is that my view will only display the last row of the query results

Model:

```
$this->db->select('Caption,Description');                           
$query = $this->db->get_where('Events', array ('User_iduser' => $user_id));
$results = $query->result();
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('get_events_model');
$data['results'] = $this->get_events_model->get_events(); 
$this->load->view('main/members_area_form',$data);
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($results as $row); {
echo $row->Caption;
echo $row->Description;
}
?>
```

To troubleshoot I have put:

```
var_dump($results);
```

...in the view and the result is:

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (2) { ["Caption"]=> string(5) "Color"     ["Description"]=> string(4) "Blue" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#19 (2) { ["Caption"]=> string(5) "Color" ["Description"]=> string(3) "Red" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) { ["Caption"]=> string(5) "Color" ["Description"]=> string(5) "Black" } }
```

So there is nothing wrong with the db query but still the foreach loop is only displaying the last row from the query. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
remove ";" from 
<?php foreach($results as $row); {

the line will be 
<?php foreach($results as $row) {

in your case foreach was only looping but your echos was not in foreach.
after executing foreach 
it was coming to your echo part and echoing last row as foreach already conpleted its loop.
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Its working now, and it all makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

look at your view code:

you should remove your unnecessary semicolon ";"
after the foreach

```
<?php 
     foreach($results as $row) {
        echo $row->Caption;
        echo $row->Description;
     }
?>
```